# Multiple meanings of polarizability?

Tags: dielectric, linear-systems

There's a concept in linear response theory called the polarizability $\chi$
$$\tag{1} \rho_{ind}=\int \chi(\vec{r},\vec{r}',t-t') V_{ext} \: d\vec{r}' dt' $$
where $\rho_{ind}$ is the induced charge and $V_{ext}$ is an external potential.  The polarizability is sometimes called the density response function (because according to Kubo, it is a density-density correlation function).

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizability) features a concept $\alpha$ called "polarizability" given by
$$\tag{2} \vec{p}=\alpha \vec{E} $$
where $\vec{p}$ is an atomic dipole moment and $\vec{E}$ is an external electric field.  I know $\chi$ and $\alpha$ are related, but are they the same thing?  They don't look the same to me, but I find it confusing that we would name two different concepts (both related to dielectric screening) "polarizability".

Furthermore, adding to the confusion, we denote the [electric susceptibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_susceptibility) $\chi_e$ given by
$$\tag{1} \vec{P}=\int \chi_e(\vec{r},\vec{r}',t-t') \vec{E} \: d\vec{r}' dt' $$
Despite sharing the same symbol, the polarizability $\chi$ and the electric susceptibility $\chi_e$ are also not the same thing, right?  If I remember correctly, in Fourier space (or in real space with appropriate integral symbols included), the dielectric constant is $\epsilon = 1+\chi_e$ and $1/\epsilon = 1 + V_{Coulomb} \chi$.  Also, $\epsilon$ and $\alpha$ are related by [Clausius–Mossotti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius%E2%80%93Mossotti_relation).

So, to summarize my question: Are either $\alpha$ or $\chi_e$ the same as $\chi$, or are they three distinct (but related) entities?  When I say "distinct", I mean that they aren't related by trivial factors (such as multiplication by $4\pi$ or addition of constants).  I suspect that they are all different things.